# Problems encoding an HTA file to run Java+Batch files for DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, scripting, java, batch

I'm having a problem coding a .HTA file, and I really need some help. I've been searching all over the place and I can't seem to find what I need to add to this code to make it run. I'm trying to get the HTA script (running javascript) to, utilizing a .BAT file as well, pull information from a list of websites that need to be added to the Forward Lookup Zones of my DNS Server, and add a New Host (A) to the newly created Zone. I need the batch file to pull from a pre-created .txt file that has all the websites that need to be blocked. The .txt file says, for example:

```
website.number.1.com
website.number.2.com
website.number.3.com
website.number.4.com
```

All the way through the 2000+ sites that need to be added to it. I want the batch file to add the zone website.number.1.com, add a host of 127.0.0.1, and then do the same thing for website.number.2.com, website.number.3.com, and so on throughout the list. I know you can edit pretty much all of the DNS from the CMD prompt, but is there a way to make it go down the list and add all of the sites in the .txt file?

Comment: Why not just directly load a custom zone file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of zones is in `zonelist.txt` this will do what you want:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (zonelist.txt) do (
  dnscmd SERVER /ZoneAdd %%i /Primary
  dnscmd SERVER /RecordAdd %%i @ A 127.0.0.1
)
```

Using an `hta` file and Javascript is over-complicating the problem.

Comment: The job that was left to me was half-assed in an HTA file and he was asking me to make a .bat file. I tried putting that in but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm doing it on my non-privaliged account at the moment so that I can be sure that it's going to work and I'm not going to have to go over it again, because there's so many sites... I have a small list I'm testing it on, and when I do either command from CMD, it seems to work, but when I try to input it into a .bat file, it doesn't seem to be working. I can't even get it to pause after the script so I can see what it's doing. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, look at dostips.com  .   They have ideas for most everything you might encounter.